# How to get value from each column of an sqlite record?

Tags: android, sqlite

My sql should return only one record that contains three columns. Funcioando is properly since I am debugging the code to better understand my problem. I need to get the value of each column to move to a ClienteVO class. But he brings the three columns but the first picks in the second when will the error `Can1t read row # 0, col # -1 from CursorWindow`
I checked debugging and column names are correct and the record returns.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new DB(ctx).getReadableDatabase();

String sql = String.format("select limite,valor,nome from limite " +
            " INNER JOIN cliente ON cliente.id = limite.cliente_id " +
            "where cliente.id=1");

Cursor rs = db.rawQuery( sql, null);
ClienteVO vo = null;

if (rs != null){
    vo = new ClienteVO();
    rs.moveToFirst();

    vo.setLimite(rs.getFloat(rs.getColumnIndex("limite")));
    vo.setValor(rs.getFloat(rs.getColumnIndex("valor")));
    vo.setNome(rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("nome")));
}
```

Then read about researching iterate over the columns. And he traverses three columns normally. I wonder if it's the only way to get these values and what is the best way to get the attributes.

```
Cursor rs = db.rawQuery( sql, null);        
ClienteVO vo = null;

if (rs != null){
    vo = new ClienteVO();
    rs.moveToFirst();

    for (Integer i=0; i <= rs.getColumnNames().length; i++ ){
       //How can I get the values of clean way
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your "sql" variable ?

Comment: Sorry should have shared faciliar for understanding. Have you edited the question.

Comment: That variable is not called `sql`. Is this really the code you're using?

Comment: Yes, I corrected the name of the string in question. I still have this problem I can not get the column values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Cursor rs = db.rawQuery( sql, null);

    ClienteVO vo = null;

    vo = new ClienteVO();
    if (rs.moveToFirst()) {
            vo.setLimite(rs.getFloat(0));
            vo.setValor(rs.getFloat(1));
            vo.setNome(rs.getString(2));
    }
```

You can write this.

```
   Cursor rs = db.rawQuery( sql, null);
```

Above you have sql variable. What does it contain?

Okay, you should use next

```
if (rs.moveToFirst()) {//}
```

to check if your cursor has at least one row.

Comment: I already tried but it just does not run between the columns as I explained.